# SSE and Concurrency with Rails 4 and Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, server-sent-events, puma

I tried to ask this before, but I wasn't clear enough about what I was trying to find out.

I am building an app for a client, and he wants to have users go to a page and push out data to all of those users simultaneously at particular times.

For example, he might want to be able to send them all the same link at 4:15 pm

Anyway, this seemed like a perfect use case for server-sent events. I'm not that familiar with sse, but I thought I would check it out. I started with this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live

This seems to suggest that you need a new concurrent connection for every new user on the page. This answer seems to confirm that: [Server Sent Events and Rails Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592865/server-sent-events-and-rails-streaming)

For every new user on the page, do I need a new thread running? Is a new thread the same as a new concurrent connection? If we had 100,000 users, that would be a crazy amount of threads.

Any suggestions about a better way to do this?

Comment: All at exact same time is impossible I suppose, unless you have an insane server... All with a few seconds delay between each is possible. And in theory you shouldn't spawn more than 1 thread per CPU Core (like CPU with 8 cores = 8 threads). Yea the good idea is using a threadpool probably, so you'll start pushing those things 8 users per time, still if there is a delay of 1 second between each 8 requests, your last user may receive the push notification after 4 hours. But maybe the delay is much more small, i have no idea.

Comment: Sorry if I don't have an answer for you, that's all I know and it's coming from game programming related stuff. If you have something permanently connected to your server than it's definitely doable (you don't have to create a thread, open a connection, push data, close connection, close thread) which is more long. Consider in any case that an MMO usually runs at most around 2000-3000 players at same time... Not 100 000